# shell: clean up leaked background processes which hang due to shared stdout/stderr

Tags: shell, process, pipe, resource-cleanup, resource-leak

I need to run essentially arbitrary commands on a (remote) shell in ephemeral containers/VMs for a test execution engine. Sometimes these leak background processes which then cause the entire command to hang. This can be boiled down to this simple command:

```
$ sh -c 'sleep 30 & echo payload'
payload
$
```

Here the backgrounded `sleep 30` plays the role of a leaked process (which in reality will be something like `dbus-daemon`) and the echo is the actual thing I want to run. The `sleep 30 & echo payload` should be considered as an atomic opaque example command here.

The above command is fine and returns immediately as the shell's and also sleep's stdout/stderr are a PTY. However, when capturing the output of the command to a pipe/file (a test runner wants to save everything into a log, after all), the whole command hangs:

```
$ sh -c 'sleep 30 & echo payload' | cat
payload
# ... does not return to the shell (until the sleep finishes)
```

Now, this could be fixed with some rather ridiculously complicated shell magic which determines the FDs of stdout/err from `/proc/$$/fd/{1,2}`, iterating over `ls /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*` and killing every process which also has the same stdout/stderr. But this involves a lot of brittle shell code and expensive shell string comparisons.

Is there a way to clean up these leaked background processes in a more elegant and simpler way? `setsid` does not help:

```
$ sh -c 'setsid -w sh -c "sleep 30 & echo payload"' | cat
payload
# hangs...
```

Note that process groups/sessions and killing them wholesale isn't sufficient as leaked processes (like dbus-daemon) often setsid themselves.

P.S. I can only assume POSIX shell or bash in these environments; no Python, Perl, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The following works but I'm unusure it answers your question: `sh -c '{ sleep 30 | cat ; } & { echo payload | cat ; }'`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not specifically looking for a solution for sleep and echo; this is just an example command for a situation "some command leaks a background command". I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: I found an initial approximation: `$ setsid -w sh -c 'sleep 30 & echo payload; RC=$?; for p in $(pgrep --pgroup 0); do [ $p = $$ ] || kill $p; done; exit $RC' | cat`   Just using `kill -- -$$` is too aggressive as it kills the shell itself too.

Comment: ... but no, that's not good enough for the real use case; leaked processes often have a new process group or even a new session, so relying on them isn't sufficient; it seems one really needs to iterate over all processes and fish out the ones sharing stdout/stderr, and blacklist your own shell. *sigh*

Comment: Not sure if you can alter the original code, but does running in a subshell help?  i.e. `sh -c '(sleep 30 & echo payload|cat)'`

Comment: @cdarke: No, it doesn't help; the point is that the outermost command's stdout is a pipe, i. e. your example would be `sh -c '(sleep 30 & echo payload)'|cat`.

Comment: OK, can a `disown -a` be inserted?  `sh -c '(sleep 30 & echo payload);disown -a|cat'`  (note the position of the end-quote)

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem with parallel tests in Launchpad. The simplest solution we had then - which worked well - was just to make sure that no processes share stdout/stdin/stderr (except ones where you actually want to hang if they haven't finished - e.g. the test workers themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, having re-read this I cannot give you the solution you are after (use systemd to kill them). What we came up with is to simply ignore the processes but reliably not hang when the single process we were waiting for is done. Note that this is distinctly different from the pipes getting closed.

Another option, not perfect but useful, is to become a local reaper with prctl(2) and PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER. This will allow you to be the parent of all the processes that would otherwise reparent to init. With this arrangement you could try to kill all the processes that have you as ppid. This is terrible but it's the closest best thing to using cgroups.

But note, that unless you are running this helper as root you will find that practical testing might spawn some setuid thing that will lurk and won't be killable. It's an annoying problem really.

Comment: For the same problem we have in plainbox (another testing tool ;-) You can look at this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/plainbox/+bug/1377270 but all the details there are the same. I'm just linking it in for easier cross-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `script -qfc` instead of `sh -c`.